Sci-Fi show with aliens that were like us
I remember this show from ~early 2000s. It was a Sci-Fi show where the humans had the ability to travel to alien planets. In the episode I remember, some humans arrived on a planet with intelligent life. These "aliens" had technology equal to what we have now as 21st Century humans.
The general theme of the episode was that these "aliens" were surrogates for us, the viewer, and were dealing with issues we deal with now (like fossil fuels). They looked human, drove jeep-like automobiles powered by fossil fuels, and had never encountered an aliens species (us) before.
The only difference from us I remember was that their ear lobes attached to their face, as opposed to dangling like ours do. And their culture didn't include kissing, as I remember in the episode the protagonist human introduced that custom to one of the aliens.
It's not Stargate.

My 1st thought was Stargate as well, but possibly Enterprise, it was on around that time as well.

Around here, we call them http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RubberForeheadAliens

Turns out it was Farscape S01E02, I, E.T.
Friend was watching the show saw the alien that matched my description and forwarded it to me. :)


She looks like Kes from Voyager too.
